# MongoDB incorrect update query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named ‘machines’ with document (Attached image) -

[Document in 'machines' collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN8PO.jpg)

Here I want to update ‘toDownload’ to false for those records which have “name” as “andwived-wx-1” and “downloads.config” as “5984b2f0ca0a093c74cb4395”.

I am using below two queries (Not working) –

db.machines.updateMany({"name": "andwived-wx-1","downloads.config":"5984b2f0ca0a093c74cb4395"},{$set: {"downloads.toDownload":false}})

db.machines.updateMany({"name": "andwived-wx-1",{downloads:{$elemMatch:{"config":"5984b2f0ca0a093c74cb4395"}}}},{$set: {"downloads:{$elemMatch:{"toDownload":false}}}})

Please suggest the right query.

Comment: Share the response that u are getting, ur query seems correct.